# Отслеживание местоположения

Tags: google-maps, gps

Нужно установить устройства на несколько машин и отправлять координаты на сайт через определенный промежуток времени, но я не знаю какое устройство для этого подойдет. Была идея написать приложения для Android, но ставить смарт на каждую машину слишком затратно + будет быстро "сажаться" батарея. Какие есть специальные устройства для таких целей?

Comment: [Вот] , первое что нашел. Работает от аккумулятора автомобиля, все данные идут через личный кабинет. Дополнительный функционал зависит от вашего бюджета [ВОт]: http://www.spyline.ru/item/view/3125/

Answer (score 1):

в любом случае апаратура должна работать от аккумулятора машины, трекеры можно купить, но можно и смарт дешёвый, написать софт для смарта - ноль проблем (я делал такой) , также нужен и софт для сервера - так же ноль проблем.
выгода самоделки любой функционал бесплатен(исключая затраты на создание), постоянные затраты - выбор тарифа для интернет трафика. я использовал для связи смарта с сервером - websocket, поэтому трафика "почти нет"